# Classify all possible $R$-module structures on a vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional complex vector space. In particular, it is an Abelian group. Let $R$ be a (commutative, unitary) $\mathbb C$-algebra.

> **Problem**. I would like to parameterize all $R$-module structures one can put on
>   $V$.

These are exactly, by definition, the elements of the set $$\hom_{\textrm{Ring}}(R,\textrm{End}_{\mathbb Z}(V)).$$
Unfortunately, I cannot do anything better. I do not even know if I can replace $\textrm{End}_{\mathbb Z}(V)$ by $\textrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(V)$, the ring of $\mathbb C$-linear endormorphisms of $V$, finally viewed as a vector space. Ideally, I would like to say that to give an $R$-module structure on $V$ is to give a tuple of endomorphisms of $V$, one for each generator of the algebra $R$.

Does anyone have any suggestion? Does the above problem have a well-known solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can replace $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{C}$, provided you also replace $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{Ring}$ with $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}\textbf{-Alg}}$. Strictly speaking this only tells you about the $R$-module structures you can put on $V$ already considered as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, but that is more reasonable than regarding $V$ as an abelian group.

Comment: Are you saying that $\hom_{\textrm{Ring}}(R,\textrm{End}_\mathbb Z(V))\cong \hom_{\mathbb C\textrm{-Alg}}(R,\textrm{End}_\mathbb C(V))$? Why is that? I would be also interested in seeing the categorical machinery that makes this possible.

Comment: I am not saying that at all. The LHS is bigger in general. What I am saying is that you are probably more interested in the RHS.

Comment: The RHS is certainly more attractive, but I want to understand the LHS (i.e. the $R$-module structures on the *vector space* $V$). According to the definition, I am forced to "forget" it is a vector space. This is what I find frustrating in the problem.

Comment: @Brenin Look: you say that you're interested in module structures on the *vector space $V$* and yet nothing about $V$'s field appears at all in the expression $\mathrm{hom}(R,End_\Bbb Z(V))$. At that point you are already considering $V$ only as an abelian group, and its vector space structure plays no role at all. If you really want to respect $V$'s $F$ structure, then you would ask for the homomorphisms to be $F$ linear as well, and then you are making use of it. You'd then be in the "right hand side" case.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes, now I understand your comment and definitely my interest is in the RHS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brenin ok! In what terms do you want to parameterize the structures?

Comment: Actually I would like to to characterize them in a nice way - and a triple of $\mathbb C$-linear endomorphism is quite nice. (Maybe the word "parameterize" was a bit inappropriate.)